# How can I find whom are the converted leads from a specific campaign?

Tags: campaign, campaign-member

I am trying to get the converted leads from a campaign.

trying to get a **Lead with converted history** didn't provide the data (no campaign info).

Following [Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/17441/260) states, that there is no direct connection between lead and campaign

Following picture shows 7 converted leads from the campaign

Is it possible to know whom these 7 leads are?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Campaigns with Leads and Converted Lead Information** report type provides this information.

[image: Campaigns with Leads and Converted Lead Information]

Answer (score 1):

Leads that have been converted during a Campaign will have both the `LeadId` and `ContactId` fields populated on their `CampaignMember` record.

You can easily get these records using SOQL:

```
SELECT Id, ...
FROM Lead
WHERE Id IN
(
    SELECT LeadId 
    FROM CampaignMember 
    WHERE CampaignId = 'YOURCAMPAIGNID' 
        && LeadId != null 
        && ContactId != null
)
```

Comment: That report made it. but better to split your answer to 2 answers. So I can accept that one :-)

Comment: @Saariko Is two answers really the best way to go? I'm happy to do it but it just seems a bit odd.

Comment: Nope. That's the correct way.

Comment: @Saariko I found a post on SE meta which said that :)